# sklearn.utils.sparsetools.connected_components fails for numpy.ones(n,n)

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, scikit-learn

I tried the following sniplet of code, unfortunately it fails because the rank of something not documented by the pydoc of `connected_components` is not 1.

```py
import numpy
from scipy.sparse import csc_matrix
from sklearn.utils.sparsetools import connected_components

connected_components(numpy.ones(shape=(3,3), dtype=numpy.bool))
```

This results in this error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "_traversal.pyx", line 75, in sklearn.utils.mst._traversal.connected_components (sklearn/utils/sparsetools/_traversal.c:1495)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/sparsetools/_graph_validation.py", line 50, in validate_graph
    nan_null=nan_null)
  File "_graph_tools.pyx", line 166, in sklearn.utils._graph_tools.csgraph_from_dense (sklearn/utils/sparsetools/_graph_tools.c:2601)
  File "_graph_tools.pyx", line 70, in sklearn.utils._graph_tools.csgraph_from_masked (sklearn/utils/sparsetools/_graph_tools.c:1816)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/compressed.py", line 88, in __init__
    self.check_format(full_check=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/compressed.py", line 156, in check_format
    raise ValueError('data, indices, and indptr should be 1-D')
ValueError: data, indices, and indptr should be 1-D
```

On the other hand, this works:

```py
connected_components(csc_matrix(numpy.ones(shape=(3,3), dtype=numpy.bool)))
#output: (1, array([0, 0, 0], dtype=int32))
```

Similarly, this also works:

```py
connected_components(numpy.zeros(shape=(3,3), dtype=numpy.bool))
#output: (1, array([0, 1, 2], dtype=int32))
```

The pydoc of `connected_components` states:

```py
graph : array_like or sparse
  The N x N matrix representation of a directed or undirected graph.
  If dense, then non-edges are indicated by zeros or infinities.
```

This suggests that numpy.matrix (which I consider array_like or dense) is a valid input. What does this error-message mean? what does it mean for data, indices, and indptr to not have rank 1? I'm assuming the dense-matrix is converted into a sparse matrix, to allow faster or easier edge traversal, and hence the data, indices, indptr are used. Yet I could not deduce what the meaning of a rank for these 3 1-D structures should be (other than 0 or 1).

What does this error mean? Is this a bug, or is this PEBKAC?

Cheers!